# Apply modifier class to specified items in an array [React]

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs, sass

```
head: {
    className: '',
    columns: ['Name', 'Title', 'Position', 'Company'],
    center: true,
  },

cp-table-head--center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

- Above is my Javascript for a table component in React.
- Underneath that is the corresponding CSS for the modifier

Does anyone know how I can apply the modifier to only certain head items in the array? Thanks.

Comment: how are you rendering it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the '[classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)' package for applying BEM inside of React, as it's a lot easier to add conditional classes / modifiers to your components. But to answer your question, I'd probably do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

const TableHead = ({ title, center = false }) => {
  const styling = classnames({
    'cp-table-head': !center,
    'cp-table-head--center': center,
  });

  return <th className={styling}>{title}</th>
}

const Table = () => {
  const columns = ['Name', 'Title', 'Position', 'Company'];
  const headers = columns.map((title) => (
    <TableHead key={title} title={title} center />
  ));

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {headers}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>body..</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

This example is relatively simple, so you could choose to just use a ternary operator for this:

```
className={`cp-table-head${center ? '--center' : ''}`}
```

To answer your question about centering specific header items.. You could use the above `TableHead` component with.. :

```
...
const Table = () => {
  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      center: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'Title',
      center: false,
    },
    {
      title: 'Position',
      center: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'Company',
      center: false,
    }
  ];

  const headers = columns.map((header, index) => (
    <TableHead key={index} title={header.title} center={header.center} />
  ));
...
```